# xubuntu apt-get install error - libjbig0 dependency issue

Tags: ubuntu

I have a problem that whenever I try to do install something using sudo apt-get I get this error. Anytime I try to install anything this error occurs. This is really breaking my system.

The error happened after I tried to install codelite.

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 libjbig0 : Breaks: libjbig0:i386 (!= 2.0-2ubuntu4.1) but 2.0-2ubuntu1 is installed
 libjbig0:i386 : Breaks: libjbig0 (!= 2.0-2ubuntu1) but 2.0-2ubuntu4.1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

I have tried the sudo apt-get install -f command and it returns:

```
gedi@gedi-XPS-8300:~$ sudo apt-get install -f
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  lib32gcc1 libc6-i386 libfakekey0 libllvm3.4:i386 libmono-addins-gui0.2-cil
  libmono-addins0.2-cil libwxbase3.0-0 libwxsqlite3-2.8-0 linux-image-generic
  qt4-qmake wine-compholio wine-compholio-amd64 wine-compholio-i386:i386
  wine-mono4.5.2 wx-common
Use 'apt-get autoremove' to remove them.
The following extra packages will be installed:
  libjbig0:i386
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libjbig0:i386
1 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/25.1 kB of archives.
After this operation, 2,048 B of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 371507 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libjbig0_2.0-2ubuntu4.1_i386.deb ...
Unpacking libjbig0:i386 (2.0-2ubuntu4.1) over (2.0-2ubuntu1) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libjbig0_2.0-2ubuntu4.1_i386.deb (--unpack):
 trying to overwrite shared '/usr/share/doc/libjbig0/changelog.Debian.gz', which is different from other instances of package libjbig0:i386
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libjbig0_2.0-2ubuntu4.1_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Thanks in advance for any clues!

Comment: I am facing the same issue. Did you get a solution to this ?